# Split and RSplit returning the same value when splitting a string

Tags: python

I have several strings in the format of (10, 12), (7, 3) etc that I want to break apart into two strings of the format string1 = 10, string2 = 12, string1 = 7, string 2 = 3 etc. I am using the following code to do this:

```
uv = uu[1:-1] #remove brackets from 'uu'
uva = uv.split(",", 1)[1] #take the first string before the ',' split
uvb = uv.rsplit(",", 1)[-1] #take the first string in reverse after the ','
```

However in the above examples 'uva' and 'uvb' would both resolve to the string after the ',' and I', not sure why.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I've tried a few variations on the variable 'uva' but i'm not getting anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you want simply:

```
uva, uvb = map(int, uv[1:-1].split(","))
```

For example:

```
>>> uv = "(10, 12)"
>>> uva, uvb = map(int, uv[1:-1].split(","))
>>> uva
10
>>> uvb
12
```

As there is only one comma `","` in each string, `split` and `rsplit` give the same result: `["10", " 12"]`. You can access these values by index:

```
 ["10", " 12"]
# ^ 0   ^ 1 (or -1)
```

*(note zero-based indexing and the use of negative indices to count back from the end)*

or simply unpack as I have done above. `map` converts both values to integers using `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
uva = uv.split(",", 1)[1] #take the first string before the ',' split
```

Index `1` is the second string, but you don’t really need to do any of this.

```
uva, uvb = uv.split(",")
```

Depending on what this format actually represents (something from `repr`?) you might consider [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead, which will get you a tuple of integers.

Answer (score 1):

Python uses 0-based indexing.  You meant

```
uva = uv.split(",", 1)[0]
```